# URL rewrite rules cannot get css,js and image in the page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

My url on server is :

`https://www.everyoneknows.com.my/customer/?loc=dashboard`

Now I want change url to:

`https://www.everyoneknows.com.my/customer/dashboard/`

In the .htaccess file, I write the rules are:

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^everyoneknows\.com\.my [OR,NC] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://www.everyoneknows.com.my%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(customer)/\?loc=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(customer)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/?loc=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Now my result in the page all css, js and images are gone, like below picture:

[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5suG.png)

Actually, I want the output included in the page all css, js and images, like below picture:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oddjs.png)

Hope someone can guide me on how to edit my url rewrite rules. Thanks.